# Reserve pts range for some users

Tags: terminal, tty

Is possible to reserve pseudo terminal range ids for some users ?

Consider an user which should get preferable (or exclusively) pts id from 500 to 600, other from 0 to 400, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The existing library interfaces do not have a way to do this.  Aside from designing and writing your own interface library: no.

Further reading:

- [grantpt, posix_openpt, ptsname, unlockpt -- pseudo-terminal access functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/grantpt.3.html)
- [openpty, login_tty, forkpty - terminal utility functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openpty.3.html)
- [pty - pseudoterminal interfaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html)

Comment: That interface would have to be in the kernel, or indirectly supported e.g. through permissions, not just in libraries. Library support could be resolved through `LD_PRELOAD` for just that user.